# Find the coefficient of $z$ in the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{e^z}{z-1}$ in ${|z| > 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I've found this duplicate from '15: [Find the coefficient of $z$ in the Laureant Series expansion of $\frac{e^z}{z-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560377/find-the-coefficient-of-z-in-the-laureant-series-expansion-of-fracezz-1), but I think it's wrong, since it looks for the Laurent expansion in ${|z-1|>1}$.

After developing it by myself, I've reached the following:

$$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z-1}\cdot e^z$$

Then, $e^z=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and $$\frac{1}{z-1}=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}$$.

Here I thought of using the Cauchy Product, but I end up with

$$f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^{2k-n-1}}{k!}$$ (How can I make this font bigger? The exponent is too small. Sorry about that. The exponent would be $2k-n-1$).

So I have to sum whenever $2k-n-1 = 1$

If I'm not getting it wrong, this means that I have to calculate $$\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{(1+2n)!}$$ (I'm not sure how to show it better, but I've put the first 3 terms and were $\frac{1}{1!}, \frac{1}{3!}$ and $\frac{1}{5!}$. I'm not sure how to calculate that. The nearest thing I thought was that $$\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!}=e $$. Maybe what I found before could be considered as an answer, but I think I can go one step further.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{e^z}{z-1} = e^z \cdot \frac{1}z \cdot \frac1{1-\frac1z} = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n}}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\right)$$

so the coefficient of $z$ is equal to

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n!} = e-2$$

It is because $z$ is obtained when multiplying the term $\frac{z^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}$ from the first sum, with the term $\frac1{z^{k+1}}$ from the second sum:

$$\frac{z^2}{2!}\cdot \frac1z + \frac{z^3}{3!}\cdot \frac1{z^2} + \frac{z^4}{4!}\cdot \frac1{z^3} + \cdots = z \left(\frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + \cdots \right)$$

Comment: I've reached the hint, but I can't find why it's true your next afirmation. Also, I think that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}=e-2$

Comment: @DaniSeidler Yes, thanks. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I was complicating it a lot. It's all clear now, thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

We denote with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series.

> We obtain for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n]\frac{e^z}{z-1}&=[z^{n}]\frac{e^z}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}\tag{1}\\
> &=[z^{n+1}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{z^j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}[z^{n+1-k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{z^j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}&\qquad n\geq 0\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}&\qquad n< 0\\
> \end{array}
> \right.\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=}\left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \color{blue}{e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}}&\color{blue}{\quad\, n\geq 0}\\
> \color{blue}{e}&\color{blue}{\quad\, n< 0}\\
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $z$.
- In (2) and (3) we use $[z^p]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $z^{n+1-k}$.

> We conclude the Laurent expansion of $\frac{e^z}{z-1}$ in $|z|>1$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{e^z}{z-1}=e\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}z^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\right)z^n}
> \end{align*}

Comment: The coefficient notation was new to me. Interesting!